# Outlook Add-in is disabled when forward event on Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Just faced with strange behavior on Outlook for Mac. When a user creates an event, add attendees, save and close, then select it and press the button "Forward" it opens a new message window with disabled my Outlook Add-In (open Add-in button is disabled). When I do the same on Outlook for Window the Add-in button is enabled and Add-in works fine.

**What is the reason to change behavior on Mac and Windows? Is it an issue?**

Stable repro, I use the same o365 account (there is no difference between the Add-in manifest then), Outlook for Mac 16.36 (20030502), Outlook for Windows 2006 (build 13001.20384 Click-to-Run) Current chanel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding forwarding an event in Outlook Mac and addins being disabled. We are able to reproduce this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: Thanks, hope you will be able to fix it someday :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for confusion earlier. We do not support add-ins in the event forward scenario by design in Outlook Mac.

However, read mode add-ins are supported in event forward scenario (with the exception of item.getBody APIs) in the New Outlook for Mac, which is currently available in our Insiders program. You can get access to it by signing up for the Insiders program [here](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/mac).